# Figure de style : Question à laquelle on répond immédiatement

Tags: linguistique, figure-de-style

Quelle est la figure de style utilisée dans la phrase suivante ?

**"Qui serait capable de résister à un bonbon ? Personne!"**

Il s'agit d'une question rhétorique, mais existe-t-il une figure plus précise pour le fait de donner la réponse immédiatement ?

En anglais il y a l'[hypophora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophora), mais je n'ai pas trouvé son équivalent français, s'il existe.

Comment: Ton exemple d'emploi est à mon avis un peu léger si on ne lit pas l'article de Wikipedia en entier, et, à mon avis encore, je pense qu'il vaudrait mieux renvoyer à des définitions plus claires du mot que celle de wikipedia. Les réponses à la question posée sur ELU [Status of 'hypophora' as a word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462739/status-of-hypophora-as-a-word) renvoient à des définitions que, personnellement, je trouve plus claires et montre bien que le terme n'est pas courant en anglais.

Comment: [→](https://www.louis-marchand.fr/2019/03/19/nouveau-guide-pratique-des-principales-figures-de-rhetorique/#HYPOPHORE**) L’Hypophore est une figure de style dans laquelle l’orateur pose une question, puis répond à la question.  L’hypophore peut consister en une question unique à laquelle le communicant répond par une phrase unique, mais aussi par une série de questions auxquelles le communicant répond par des développements plus ou moins longs. La curiosité du lecteur ou de l’auditeur est stimulée par la formulation de questions notamment celles auxquels ils n’auraient pas pensé.

Comment: [→](https://fr.411answers.com/a/quel-est-le-but-d-une-question-rhetorique.html) ... hypophore, qui est utilisée pour contrôler une discussion en posant une question et en y répondant. Ce type de question rhétorique est souvent utilisé dans les débats politiques pour impliquer une position ou pour défier un adversaire avec une affirmation négative. Un exemple d'hypophore est : «Qu'est-ce que mon adversaire a déjà fait pour nous ? Rien. La question ne se pose pas pour demander quelles bonnes actions l'adversaire a faites, mais elle insinue que l'adversaire n'a rien fait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En effet, on dirait qu'il n'y a pas de mot usuel pour cette figure de style. On pourrait déduire le mot "hypophore" mais il ne serait probablement pas compris.

La page wikipédia anglaise mentionne l'*anthypophora*, qui est légèrement différente, on soulève une objection à son argument qu'on va réfuter soi-même, plutôt que de laisser à son interlocuteur le soin de le faire. L'effet est assez différent d'une question à laquelle on répond soi-même.

On trouve cependant le mot **anthypophore** dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/anthypophore), mais il est considéré comme rare et désuet.

Ce qu'il y a de plus proche est déjà peu courant et désuet donc je doute qu'il y ait un terme usité pour le cas de la question.

Comment: Quelle différence fais-tu entre procédé rhétorique et figure de style ? Moi je fais partie de ceux qui n'en font pas.  [Un procédé rhétorique, aussi appelé figure de style](https://www.letudiant.fr/bac/devenez-incollable-sur-les-procedes-litteraires.html).  En anglais le terme *anthypophora* existe aussi, certains font la différence avec *hypophora*, pas tous, et aucun des deux n'est connu de la majorité des gens, pas plus que *hypophore* et *anthypophore* en français. Tous ces termes sont des termes de spécialistes.

Comment: @None Bonne question. Pour moi, une figure de style est une figure en littérature principalement, servant à "faire joli", agrémenter, embellir un texte. Je ne savais pas que "procédé rhétorique" était un synonyme. Pour moi, un procédé rhétorique était une technique servant à débattre, argumenter, convaincre un auditoire, pas un outil artistique. Évidemment, les deux sont très proches et ne sont pas mutuellement exclusifs.

Comment: @None mais cette distinction n'existe que dans ma tête, je vais éditer ma réponse. Merci pour cette correction.

Comment: *Hypophora* n'est pas non plus compris par la quasi majorité des anglais ([→](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/462739/12918)) et ne se trouve pas dans les dictionnaires usuels. Hypohore est dans le Littré et utilisé par les spécialistes (voir liens plus haut). Le jour où quelqu'un le mettra dans le wiktionnaire, il y sera aussi !